# Laptop won't turn back on after closing lid

Tags: suspend, laptop, screen, macbook, macbook-pro

I've tried several versions of Ubuntu and can't get this working, whenever I close and open the laptop, it has a black screen and nothing will turn it back on (I have to reboot), oddly enough the keyboard back light still works...

I'm using a 16" 2016 Macbook Pro with Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Well, I must admit, I am not sure, but I think it wouldn't hurt to take a look on this wiki page: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html Maybe you'll find something useful there.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain it somehow relates to ACPI as the problem disappears when turning off ACPI or hardware P-state (boot options `acpi=off` or `intel_pstate=no_hwp`), however that's of course not a viable solution. You could find workarounds by more or less skilled peoples but the solution remains in the kernel. All the workarounds I've tested to fix Lid Close Freeze issue had negative impacts on something else, it fixes a problem by creating others, ie. `acpi=off` disables lot of cool power and hardware kernel features. It's a pity.

On my Thinkpad model, for example, I had to wait for a newer kernel with `thinkpad_acpi` updated. Pretty sure it's the same problem for you: kernel doesn't "know" yet all the features and specifications of some of your hardware components.

Ubuntu team's supported v4.4.0-18 for xenial should have fixed it on my computer according to some bug reports like [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1561974), but in fact I had to wait for testing upstream kernel v4.5.2 to be able to close the lid without desktop freeze, surely because I'm not patient enough. Just to be clear in this example, I will continue to regularly test the lastest iterations of official v4.4.0-x until the fix is implemented, then will revert back to this LTS kernel for more reliabilty. So I hope it's just a temporary solution.

#### Backup first!!!

My very first advice will always be to **love and cherish your dear [Clonezilla boot CD/USB](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-image-and-clone-hard-drives-clonezilla)** before touching anything about kernel and the heart of your system, this way you'll be able to safely revert back changes ;)

## Safest Solution

Start *Synaptics Package Manager*, open *Settings* top-bar menu > *Repositories* > *Developer Options* tab, and enable *Pre-released updates*. Indeed your issue may have been fixed in latest v4.4.0-x.

So it's safer to try this before any exotic solution like the wild method described below, it's not advisable to play too much with a Long-Term Support release's kernel versions, at least if you want to keep the stability advantage of LTS. This `xenial-proposed` repo currently provides kernel version 4.4.0-36.55 with its **extra package** (= less chances of compatibility errors after reboot).

## Wild Wild Way

Upgrade your kernel version, the problem may have been fixed in most recent kernels. Read how to do this and what to be careful about at [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Preparing_to_install_an_upstream_kernel). The link under **Upstream kernels archive** title in this page is where you'll find the packages to install. It could be of some interest to read this [Wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelFAQ#Kernel.2FFAQ.2FGeneralUbuntuDelta.What_differentiates_the_Ubuntu_Kernel_from_the_upstream_Linux_Kernel.3F) about upstream kernel differences.

As of today I would recommend you to try [v4.6.3-yakkety](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.3-yakkety/) and if your issue isn't fixed yet, please try [v4.7.1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.1/). No extra package is available for this mainline builds anyway, so you have to understand what you do before doing it, don't complain if this kernels kill your kittens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known I/O problem with Macbook pros and usually has nothing to do with the operating systems. Usually the manufacturer's (Apples's) solution would be to replace that circuit for a couple of hundred dollars. However, if you are running ubuntu, you are in luck, because you can tell your machine not to go to sleep when the lid is closed. To do so,

1. You need to edit a file, named logind.conf in /etc/systemd/logind.conf , but it can be edited using this command in your terminal:
   **sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf**
2. At the bottom of the text, add: **HandleLidSwitch=ignore**
3. Execute this coomand to restart your systemd daemon and have the command settle in, otherwise it won't work. 
   **sudo service systemd-logind restart**   (for ubuntu 15+)

I strongly advise you don't run your Macbook pro on closed lid for a long time as it will cause ventilation problems and quickly heats up the system.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem with my laptop. I've found that if I lock Ubuntu (go to the little gear in the upper right corner and select Lock) it won't freeze up and become unresponsive. Not sure why that works but just closing the lid doesn't... I hope that helps some.